# How does a threading.Timer wait, internally (low-level thread)?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, sleep, python-multithreading

Out of curiosity, I wanted to study how `threading.Timer` works internally for the "waiting" part. I wanted to see if there was a `time.sleep(timeout)` involved or something more advanced.

So I looked at the Python [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py#L1238) for `Timer`:

- when using `start()` on a `Timer` (subclass of `Thread`), it calls `_bootstrap`, `_bootstrap_inner` and eventually `run()`:

  ```
  self.finished.wait(self.interval)
  if not self.finished.is_set():
      self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)  # finally calls the function that does the job!
  self.finished.set()
  ```
- so the sleeping part is done inside `wait(timeout)` of the `Event` instance `self.finished`.
- `Event.wait` uses `wait()` of the `Condition` instance `self._cond`.
- `Condition.wait` uses `waiter.acquire(True, timeout)`, for an object `waiter` created with `waiter = _allocate_lock()`.
- `_allocate_lock` comes from:

  ```
  import _thread
  _allocate_lock = _thread.allocate_lock
  ```

Then I am stuck: I don't find `_thread.py` except in `C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\future\moves` but I can't find where is defined `allocate_lock` and what `waiter.acquire(True, timeout)` really does internally.

**Question: where is defined `_thread`'s `allocate_lock` and `acquire`, and what internal mechanism does it use for waiting?** `time.sleep()` or something more low-level?

Comment: The module names starting with `_` are usually a C implementation. There are only so many things you can do without making machine-specific assumptions, in particular, calls to OS functionality that was implemented in C and exposes a C interface.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Good to know! In which C source file could I look  to know what `_thread`'s  `allocate_lock` / `acquire` does? Also in which binary/compiled lib is it? I have seen &_dummy_thread.py` (but acquire is not there) and also `C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\jedi\third_party\typeshed\stdlib\3\_thread.pyi`? I doubt it's there, I don't know what this jedi is.